# How to rewrite ALL urls while skipping certain folders?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to rewrite my urls to goto a single php file:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(?:(?!style|js).)*$ http://www.domain.com/single.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

However the exclusion of /dir/js and /dir/style isn't working as i was hoping it would...

- [redirects] domain.com/dir
- [redirects] domain.com/dir/jason
- [redirects] domain.com/dir/jason/pete
- [DOESN'T REDIRECT: GOOD] domain.com/dir/js
- [DOESN'T REDIRECT: GOOD] domain.com/dir/js/*
- [DOESN'T REDIRECT: BAD] domain.com/dir/**js**on

**How can I change the regular expression to match my needs?**

Comment: You probably meant to write '.*)' and not '.)*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `style|js` with `style\b|js\b`.

Maybe `RewriteCond` could be of use like in

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/(style|js)($|/)
RewriteRule ^/dir/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/single.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix my broken syntax. The / at the end of yours should be optional. Otherwise domain.com/js will redirect.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

domain.com/dir/json doesn't redirect because it doesn't match the regex.

The reason /dir/json doesn't redirect is because js follows dir/, and your regex only matches when dir/ is not followed by *either* style or js.  I think negative lookaheads are the wrong approach.  I think what you actually want is something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/(js|style)(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/single.php?uri=$1 [LQSA]
```

That basically means if the URL *isn't* ended with /js or /style (optionally with further path components underneath those dirs), *then* apply the redirect rule.

Answer (score 0):

Either with your negative look-ahead assertion:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(?!(?:style|js)(?:/|$))(.*) http://www.example.com/single.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

But that’s not so nice.

Or you just add another test on how `$1` starts:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(style|js)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*) http://www.example.com/single.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```